# Ionic3 FirebaseDynamiLinks plugin_not_installed

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, firebase-dynamic-links

When calling

```
firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink()
```

I get the warnings

```
console.warn: Native: tried calling FirebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink, but the FirebaseDynamicLinks plugin 
is not installed. 
console.warn: Install the FirebaseDynamicLinks plugin: 'ionic plugin add 
cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks'
```

But the plugin is installed:

```
ionic cordova plugin
> cordova plugin ls
✔ Running command - done!
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 1.1.0 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.3.0 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 0.10.1 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks 0.10.1 "FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.2.1 "Universal Links Plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-deploy 0.6.7 "IonicDeploy"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

The method call throws the error

```
plugin_not_installed
```

Comment: are you trying in a device? Also , did you call inside `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`?

Comment: Calling in platform.ready() ist working. Thanks!

Comment: @suraj could you please add that as the answer, so that we can then close the issue? :)

Comment: @sebaferreras ok..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to always access any ionic native/cordova plugin within `platform.ready()`

Do:

```
constructor(private platform:Platform){}
```

And in when you call the plugin:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() =>{
  firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink();
  //....
 });
```

Comment: I am facing the similar issue for networkinterface plugin. Tried calling inside platform ready event as well. But still facing the same issue. Any other options to solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just I got to see an issue filed in the plugin github for the same.